# circle shape is not looking circle in rStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tested the below code but the circle shape in the plot is not looking like a circle. Are there any settings in RStudio which I should change?

```
library(ggplot2)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:5 , y = 1:25, z = 1:25)
s <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y))
s + geom_point(aes(shape = z), size = 6) + scale_shape_identity()
```

[image: plot result]

Comment: @user10201620, welcome to SO. +1 for providing a reproducible example.

Comment: Are you referring to the jaggedness of the circle-lines? That is a matter of how the graphics device and display handles smoothing. If you save your plot e.g. as a pdf or a png with high dpi using `ggsave(...)`, you will find that they are indeed round circles. I use Windows as well an used to be a bit jealous of Linux and Mac-Users because their font and line smoothing (anti-aliasing) is system-wide ;) If you want smooth lines inside R-Studio, it is worth checking out the `Cairo`-Package, which offers a graphics device with good anti-aliasing.

Comment: thanks! that helps.